# compare 2 dictionary by values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to compare 2 large dictionaries (more than 600k keys).

```
dict_old = {
    1: {'value_1' : 'foo', 'value_2' : 'bar', ...},
    2: {'value_1' : 'abc', 'value_2' : 'def', ...},
    3: {....},
    }

dict_new = {
    1: {'value_1' : 'abc', 'value_2' : 'def', ...},
    2: {'value_1' : '222', 'value_2' : '333', ...},
    3: {'value_1' : 'foo', 'value_2' : 'bar', ...},
    4: {'value_1' : 'abc', 'value_2' : 'def', ...},
    ...
    }
```

I´ve to create a new dictionary with the changes only.

```
dict_update = {
    1: {'value_1' : 'abc', 'value_2' : 'def', ...},
    2: {'value_1' : '222', 'value_2' : '333', ...},
    ...
    }
```

The keys are rolling numbers and not the same in old/new dictionary. So I´m using 2 for loops to do the job. 
The process runs more the 60 minutes.

```
dict_update = {}

for key_new in dict_new.keys():
    for key_old in dict_old.keys():
        if dict_new[key_new] == dict_old[key_old]:
            add = False
            break
        else:
            add = True

    if add:
        dict_update[key_new] = dict_new[key_new]
```

Is there a faster/more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: What counts as a "change" here? It looks like your first change is a value that's identical in both dict_old and dict_new (`dict_old[2] == dict_new[1]`), your second change is a value that's only in dict_new (`dict_new[2])`), while you're skipping over other values that are in both dicts (`dict_old[1] == dict_new[3]`), so I can't figure out what rule you're trying to implement.

Comment: It _might_ be as simple as something like `old_values = set(dict_old.values()` and then `dict_update = {key: value for key, value not in dict_new.items() if value in old_values}` or something, which would turn your quadratic nested loop into a linear flat loop (since you can do set lookups in constant time). But that obviously isn't correct for your desired output, and without understanding why the desired output is what it is, I don't know if it's possible to do something similar that _is_ correct.

Comment: dict_old[1] == dict_new[3] is possible, the keys are not important - i need to compare only the values

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't answer my question at all. Why is that first row in `dict_update`? Why is that second row in `dict_update`? Why is there nothing corresponding to row 3 in `dict_update`? Why is there only one row corresponding to rows 1 and 4 when they're identical? I can't even figure it out by running your code, because, even if I remove all the `...` to turn your example into a runnable example, your code doesn't produce the same output as your example output.

Comment: If you are only comparing values (i.e., the keys 1,2,3... don't matter), then why is `{'value_1' : 'abc', 'value_2' : 'def', ...}` in `dict_update`? If only the values matter then @abarnert's set solution is good.

Comment: correct !!! sorry !!! dict_update = {3: {'value_1' : 'abc', 'value_2' : 'def', ...}, 4: {'value_1' : '222', 'value_2' : '333', ...},
    ...
    }

Comment: @PaulHansen That makes even _less_ sense, and it's even _farther_ from what your existing code produces. You've got the exact same values, but now the keys don't seem to correspond to anything.

Comment: Also, whenever you figure out how to correct your question, please [edit] the question to be right, don't just put comments below saying that it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess here: What you want is all key-values pairs in `dict_new` where there's no equal value in `dict_old`.

The problem with your code is that, for each key-value pair in `dict2`, you're doing a linear search through all of `dict1`. So, this takes `O(N*M)` time (where `N=len(dict2)` and `M=len(dict1)`), which is very slow.

But if you can had the values from `dict1` in a set, you wouldn't need that linear search; you could just do a constant-time `in` test. And you could build that set just once at the start. So now it's just `O(N+M)`, which is much better.

---

The only problem is that your values are dictionaries, and you can't store dictionaries in a set, because they're mutable.

There are a few ways around this, but the simplest is to just transform the dicts into something that is hashable, in a way that preserves equality. For example, a tuple of the sorted key-value pairs is hashable (assuming the inner values are hashable and the keys are sortable, both of which are true here), and will be equal whenever the original dicts were equal.

So:

```
dict_old = {
    1: {'value_1' : 'foo', 'value_2' : 'bar'},
    2: {'value_1' : 'abc', 'value_2' : 'def'},
    }

dict_new = {
    1: {'value_1' : 'abc', 'value_2' : 'def'},
    2: {'value_1' : '222', 'value_2' : '333'},
    3: {'value_1' : 'foo', 'value_2' : 'bar'},
    4: {'value_1' : 'abc', 'value_2' : 'def'},
    }   

def transform(d):
    return tuple(sorted(d.items()))

set_old = set(transform(d) for d in dict_old.values())

dict_update = {key: value for key, value in dict_new.items()
               if transform(value) not in set_old}
```

Notice that this does not give you your desired output, it just gives you this:

```
{2: {'value_1': '222', 'value_2': '333'}}
```

But your existing code gives you the exact same thing, and it seems to be the thing you're asking for.

Comment: In my version I've included the key in the "transform"; we can only guess what the OP really wants.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a nested loop over the keys. Instead you can just check if the `key_new` is in the `dict_old` and if it is, compare the values and make the update.

```
for key_new in dict_new.keys():
    if (dict_old.get(key_new) and dict_old[key_new] == dict_new[key_new]):
        dict_update[key_new] = dict_old[key_new]
```

Comment: "The keys are rolling numbers and not the same in old/new dictionary." Your answer assumes the keys line up, so it won't do what the OP wants. (I don't actually know what the OP _does_ want, other than "not this", though…)

Comment: That should be `dict_old.get(key_new) and ...`.  If there is no such key in the dict, `dict_old[key_new]` will raise a `KeyError`.

Comment: No it does not assume that the keys lines up. It assumes OP only cares about keys that are already in new_dict. That if statement will not preform the second check if key_new is not in dict_old. Although I do agree, I'm not really sure what OP's goal is. This was more so to illustrate there need only be 1 for loop.

Comment: You're asking for `dict_old[key_new] == dict_new[key_new]`. That assumes the keys line up. he wants to handle cases where `dict_old[some_key] == dict_new[some_other_key]`.

Comment: Ah I see, I misunderstood what the keys lining up meant then. Thanks for clarifying. Best to delete this answer?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
dict_old = {
    1: {'value_1' : 'foo', 'value_2' : 'bar'},
    2: {'value_1' : 'abc', 'value_2' : 'def'}
    }

dict_new = {
    1: {'value_1' : 'abc', 'value_2' : 'def'},
    2: {'value_1' : '222', 'value_2' : '333'},
    3: {'value_1' : 'foo', 'value_2' : 'bar'},
    4: {'value_1' : 'abc', 'value_2' : 'def'},
    }


old_hashes = set((k, frozenset(v.items())) for k, v in dict_old.items())

dictionary_update = {k: v for k, v in dict_new.items()
                     if (k, frozenset(v.items())) not in old_hashes}
```

The rationale here (if that's what you're looking for) is that whenever a rolling number + key and its values are not in the `dict_old`, then it gets added to the `dict_update`.

You should be able to tweak this code in case it does not exactly do yet what you need (e.g. also do it in the opposite direction, and add those to the `dict_update`).

Comment: That just returns all 4 values, because now nothing matches. Which _might_ be what the OP wants, but I don't think it is.